# How to write an interface, that will not allow me to access uninitialized properties of class? TypeScript

Tags: typescript, class, interface

interfaces are still puzzling me a little. I am aware, that interfaces are mostly meant for public properties or so, but I would like to have an interface, that will prevent me from accessing uninitialized properties. I can access `this.material` without error, while it is `undefined`.

Currently my code is:

```
interface ColliderConstructorArgumentInterface {
    radius:number,
    position?:THREE.Vector3
}

export interface Collider extends ColliderConstructorArgumentInterface {
    geometry:THREE.SphereGeometry
    material:THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
    mesh:THREE.Mesh
    position:THREE.Vector3
}

export class Collider {

    constructor(settings:ColliderConstructorArgumentInterface) {

        this.radius = settings.radius;
        this.position = settings.position ? settings.position : new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);

        this.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(this.radius, 8, 8);
        this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);

        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

So I have two interfaces, first one describes class constructor argument and second deals with other properties the class should have.

But as you can see, I am using property `material`, while setting up `this.mesh`, but I have not initialized it in constructor, and I am not getting any error or warning.

...

**How is it possible to adjust my interfaces to get an error message?**

I would like to have my code safe and neat.

...

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: Don't use an interface? https://tsplay.dev/Nll25N

Comment: It's not like that interface is doing anything in the first place: https://tsplay.dev/wR0XLm due to [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, you are saying that when you have:

```
this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);
```

that that point, `this.material` is `undefined`?

Well, I do not see a place on your class where you have those properties anywhere. perhaps you are just leaving them out for the posing of this question?

Here's what I would suggest, but keep in mind that I feel like I'm missing some piece of code or other information from you.

---

use `strict` mode in Typescript, which will force you to define types and flag areas where things might be undefined. https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict

Prefix interfaces with a capital letter I, this will help you to easily see what things are interface and what are not. This way you don't have to write `Interface` at the end either.

I removed the `position` field from the `ICollider` interface, since it's extending an interface that already has that property.

I added an `implements` to your class, so that it now explicitly gets the required properties from the interface you made.

The properties are now defined inside the class, as required by the implemented interface.  However, as you mentioned, they are not all initialized to values.

```
interface IColliderConstructorArgument {
  radius:number,
  position?:THREE.Vector3
}

export interface ICollider extends IColliderConstructorArgument {
  geometry:THREE.SphereGeometry
  material:THREE.MeshBasicMaterial
  mesh:THREE.Mesh
}

export class Collider implements ICollider {

  geometry: THREE.SphereGeometry;
  material: THREE.MeshBasicMaterial;
  mesh: THREE.Mesh;
  position: THREE.Vector3;
  radius: number;

  constructor(settings: IColliderConstructorArgument) {

      this.radius = settings.radius;
      this.position = settings.position ? settings.position : new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);

      this.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(this.radius, 8, 8);
      this.mesh = new THREE.Mesh(this.geometry, this.material);

      console.log(this);
  }
  
}
```

As far as `this.material` ... well, yes you do need to give that a value.  Enabling `strict` mode will probably force that on you now. I suspect this was your issue before.

Comment: Thank you, I will check that in few hours!

Comment: Great!  One tip about interfaces, keep in mind that they are not actual code, meaning when you compile to JS the interfaces are not there at all. They do not "do" anything other than define a contract of how certain objects or classes look.  You use them so that you get code completion for things, and compile errors when you forget to include other things.

Comment: Thank you, I marked your answer as correct. My issue was, as you pointed out, that I overestimated interfaces. I originally wanted to apply properties to a class by only typing them once - I expected that both interfaces will **literally** extend my class... (wrong as it seems) So I am now keeping properties under my class and thus this "smart" intermediate interface solves actually nothing, so I removed it and now I only have the first interface for argument, which is *implemented* by the class... So, what I wanted to achieve probably works only for classes, right?

Comment: Also thanks for suggesting using "I" as the first letter for naming interfaces.. my approach seemed quite verbose.

Comment: Very glad that helped!  I suggest taking a look at how your code actually compiles down to JS in the end.  Typings obviously don't since JS has no "types", and interfaces are really just more complex types.  https://www.typescriptlang.org/play